# Unable to log into mysql with phpmyadmin

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to the docker world and maybe I'm missing something.
I created the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always    
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
    - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
    - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password      
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wp:
    depends_on:
    - db
    image: andreccosta/wordpress-xdebug
    volumes:
    - ./wp:/var/www/html
    ports:
    - 8000:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

When i run it with docker-compose up everything goes well, but when I try to access localhost:8080 (path for phpmyadmin) and try to login i'm not able to connect to mysql.
If i try to enter the mysql container with

```
docker exec -t -i <conatiner_name> bash
```

and try to login to mysql i'm able to do it. 
I used this same file on a different computer and everything works well.
I'm running docker on ubuntu.

**UPDATE**
I solved the issue by changing the version of the mysql image from latest to 5.7.27.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Yes i receive this mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Comment: I tried to change MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress, now i receive these
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client